# My tkinter app should become an URL forwarding app that lets to select the browser to get the link, I just can not isolate the system URL parameter

Tags: tkinter, url, browser

I build a tkinter app that is acting as a default browser.
The problem is that I can not catch the system as it passes the URL
to the default browser:

```
cmd_param = sys.argv
 
if len(cmd_param) > 1:
     paramter = cmd_param[1] else:
     parameter = "itcomserve.de
```

I would expect that `sys.argv[1]` delivers the URL parameter.
but I am just getting an `sys.argv[0]` which is the program itself.

**any advice on this, I would greatly appreciate**

**detail explanation:**

*the GUI above produced with pyinstaller, has a list of my browser on my system. I registered this app as my standard browser. As I click an URL on my system e.g. from thunderbird, this program starts and should show that URL as a parameter in the top input field. I was hoping to get this URL parameter by sys.arg, but sys argv provides only sys.argv[0] which is the program itself. sys.argv[1](https://%20%5B2%5D:%20https://gitlab.com/ycom1/forward2browser/-/tree/master/) is missing as index.*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTDMR.png)

[enter link description here](https://%20%5B2%5D:%20https://gitlab.com/ycom1/forward2browser/-/tree/master/)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Since tkinter can't render HTML pages, it's hard to know what you really mean.

Comment: You should add those details to the question rather then burying them in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

my problem was solved, by Mr. Hölscher in discuss.python.org,
forum namely, I had to add a "%u" after the app name in the plasma
app list settings. This "%u" references the binding URL at
call.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).